# Nullable types in .NET missing methods

Tags: .net, nullable

I noticed today that if you declare a nullable DateTime object you don't get the same set of functions as you do when you have a standard DateTime object.

For example:

```
DateTime? nullableDT = DateTime.Now;
DateTime regularDT = DateTime.Now;
```

in the code above nullableDT cannot use any of the following functions:

```
ToFileTime
ToFileTimeUtc
ToLocalTime
ToLongDateString
ToLongTimeString
ToOADate
ToShortDateString
ToShortTimeString
ToString(IFormatProvider)
ToString(String)
ToString(String, IFormatProvider)
ToUniversalTime
```

This is the short list, there are many more methods not available.

Why is .NET behaving like this?  I worked around it by throwing a `Convert.ToDateTime()` around my nullable date but that seems krufty...  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you need to call [`Nullable<T>.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) to get the actual `DateTime` value.

Comment: You might also consider using `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault()` which doesn't throw an InvalidOperationException if `HasValue` is false.

Answer (score 3):

A `Nullable<T>` isn't a `T`, it just wraps a `T`. So it doesn't have the members defined on `T`. If you want to access the methods of `T`, you can do that:

```
if (nullableDT.HasValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nullableDT.Value.ToShortTimeString());
    ...
}
```